# Create and store a file to external storage

Tags: java, android, file-io

This may be a simple one for you to crack, but I cant see why this code doesn't result in creating a new file in my Android external file system? The directory is correctly created but not the file, instead I get an java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Mydir/MyFile, can anyone see what the problem is cause I can't get my eyes on it?

```
        //Generate a unique filename using date and time
    String fileName = "myFile_"+formatter_file_name.format(today)+".txt";

    //Get path to root
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    //Create(if not exists) directory in root in which to store the reports 
    File myDir = new File(root + "/myDir");   
    myDir.mkdirs();

    //Create report file object
    File file = new File (myDir, fileName);

    //If file already exists delete id(this should not be able to happen)
    if (file.exists()) file.delete(); 

    try {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fout); 

        // Write the string to the file
        osw.write("TEST STRING");

        //Ensure that everything has been written to the file and close 
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have the correct permissions in my manifest, and I will insert a check to see if external storage is available for writing but I dont't think that's the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
try {
   File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   File myFile = new File(root +"/textfile.txt");
   myFile.createNewFile();

   FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
   OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
         new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
   myOutWriter.append("String entered in file");

   myOutWriter.close();
   fOut.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: Okey, I will look at this answer and see if it helps.
But why has it been downvoted??

Comment: i also didnt get why this is downvoted. i am having this working ,,,
also you can follow this http://hoodaandroid.blogspot.in/2012/07/reading-and-writing-data-to-sdcard.html  to get all the details about reading and writing to sdcard..

Comment: I've tested your code now and it works like a charm. It was two problems with my code, first I don't call this method myFile.createNewFile() and therefore I get a FileNotFound exception. Second my file name contains non valid characters(:), and that gives me FileException(Invalid argument). It was a simple mistake;-)
I vote on your solution, thx.

Comment: Glad to help u , i also dont kw y someone downvoted my solution. GREAT :)